# Delimiter - I changed eregi to preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have problem - Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash
I changed eregi to preg_match PHP 5.3

```
$noCount=0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($robotsIP); $i++){ 
        if(preg_match($robotsIP[$i], $user_ip) || $user_ip==$robotsIP[$i]){ $noCount=1; $robot = 1; }
    }
    if(trim($user_ip)==''){ $noCount=1; $robot = 1; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess may be change this bit

```
if(preg_match($robotsIP[$i], $user_ip)
```

to

```
 if(preg_match("/".$robotsIP[$i]."/", $user_ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it might help if you show us examples of the values in the `$robotsIP` array.

Anyway, it sounds like you don't have delimiters in your string though. `preg_*` regexes need delimiters which are defined by the first character. They can be any non-alphanumeric character (which doesn't have special meaning in the regex?), but most people use `/` or sometimes I've seen `@`, especially if the regex itself needs to contain `/`s. eg:

```
preg_match("/fo{2}ba+r/", $str);
preg_match("@fo{2}ba+r@", $str);
```